# Android how to save the tab state when switching between tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have TabActivity which holds 4 tabs.

the tabs created in the tabhost activity like this

```
TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
Intent send_names_intent1 = new Intent(this,tab1.class);

//here is some data I receive it from previous activity 
//and want to send them to the tab
send_names_intent1.putExtra("names", names);        
send_names_intent1.putExtra("check", test1);

firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Kingdom I").setContent(send_names_intent1);
tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
```

in every tab the user do some work and the result will displayed in the tab,
the problem is that when switching to the 2nd tab and then go back to the 1st tab all the results will gone and the tab will be created again.

NOTICE : I tried to use the getsharedprefrences() but it will loads the saved data even if the application closed and opens again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean value `boolean test;` and int value `int last=0` then use this method

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            int currenttab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
            if (currenttab != last){
                test[last] = false;
                send_names_intent [last].putExtra("check", test[last]);
                last = currenttab;
            }

        }                                           
    });
```

when you use this method you will have a boolean value in your `tab1.class`

```
Intent names_intent = getIntent();                  
prefcheck = names_intent.getBooleanExtra("check", false);
```

then check the `prefcheck` value `if (prefcheck == false)` save the SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried onSaveInstanceState?

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  icicle.putString("names", names);
}
```

Comment: when switching between the tabs onSaveInstanceState() will not called

Answer (score 0):

You say you used shared preferences right? Why not have it so that when a tab is opened, it increments a value of a shared preference by one, and om destroy decrements it, and then checks to see if the value is 0, if so it deletes all the save preferences you want by setting them to the default value, or the value you want.

Comment: the problem is that switching between tabs and closing the app will follow the same way. so I can't make a method that uses the shared preferences only of I switch the tab. any method will save the shared preferences when switching the tab and closing the activity, so it will load the data every time.